# Obtain objects of list separated by comma

Tags: python, list

Imagine I have this List of Dictionaries:

```
my_list = [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 3}]
```

And I need to obtain only:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 3}
```

It will be passed into another function and that function does not accept Tuples nor Lists, only Dicts separated by comma.

```
_ = my_super_function_that_only_accepts_dicts_separated_by_comma(
  {"a": 1, "b": 2}, 
  {"a": 2, "b": 3},
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this would be met by a straight unpack action - put a star in front, `*my_list`. See for example how `print` works.